# Prove that the maximum of the function is attained on the end point of the interval

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on $ ℝ $ satisfying the
> inequality
> $f(x) ≤ \frac 1{2h} \int_{x+h}^{x−h}f(y)dy,∀x∈ ℝ, ∀h > 0$.
> Prove that for any bounded closed interval, the maximum of $f$
> on that interval is attained at one of its end points.

Here is an argument

Let $[a, b]$ be a bounded closed interval and let $M = max{f(x) : x ∈ [a, b]}$. We want to show that there exists a point $c$ in $[a, b]$ such that $f(c) = M$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that no such point exists. Then, we can find a sequence of points ${x_n}$ in $[a, b]$ such that $f(x_n) → M$ as $n → ∞$, but $x_n$ is not an endpoint of $[a, b]$ for any $n$.

Since $[a, b]$ is bounded, it must have a convergent subsequence. Without loss of generality, we can assume that ${x_n}$ converges to some point $c$ in $[a, b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x_n) → f(c)$ as $n → ∞$.

Applying the given inequality with $h = |x_n - c|$ and taking the limit as $n → ∞$, we get:

$M ≤ \frac 1{2|x_n - c|} \int_{c+|x_n-c|}^{c-|x_n-c|} f(y) dy$

Since $f(x_n) → M$ and $f$ is continuous, we can find a constant $δ > 0$ such that $|f(x_n) - f(c)| < ε$ for all $n$ and all $|x_n - c| < δ$, where $ε = \frac M4$.

Then, for sufficiently large $n$ such that $|x_n - c| < δ$, we have:

$M ≤ \frac 1{2|x_n - c|} \int_{c+|x_n-c|}^{c-|x_n|} f(y) dy$

≤ $\frac 1{2|x_n - c|} \int_{c+|x_n-c|}^{c-|x_n-c|} (f(c) + ε) dy$

= $\frac M2 + ε|x_n - c|$

Taking the limit as $n → ∞$, we get:

$M ≤ \frac M2$

This is a contradiction, so our assumption that no point in $[a, b]$ attains the maximum value $M$ must be false. Therefore, there exists a point $c$ in $[a, b]$ such that $f(c) = M$, and this point must be one of the endpoints of $[a, b]$.

Is this in correct way?or give another solution

Comment: In the third line of your calculation bounding M you write $$\frac{1}{2|x_n-c|}\int_{c+|x_n-c|}^{c-|x_n-c|} (f(c)+\epsilon)dy$$, where I think you mean to integrate from $c-|x_n-c|$ to $c+|x_n-c|$, and the integral of $f(c)+\epsilon$ over that interval is $2|x_n-c|(f(c)+\epsilon)$, which gives you the bound $M\leq M+\epsilon$, not $M \leq M/2 + \epsilon|x_n-c|$. It might help to consider the case where $f(x) = C$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ -- the maximum is attained at both endpoints, but also at every point in the interior of the interval.

Comment: Just note that $f$ is convex.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write $\int_{x+h}^{x-h}$ ? Did you mean to write $\int_{x-h}^{x+h} $ instead ?

Comment: I would suggest proving first that for any $c$ and any $h>0$, if there is a point $x \in (c-h, c+h)$ with $f(x) < f(c)$, then there must also be another point $x' \in (c-h, c+h)$ for which $f(x) > f(c)$. Otherwise $f(c)$ could not be $\le$ the average of $f$ on the interval. Thus if $f(c)$ is the maximum on some interval, either $f$ is constant, or else $(c-h, c+h)$ must extend outside the interval for all $h > 0$.